# Java basic specific regex needed

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for rg followed by one word separated by a space.
for example: "rg word"

I tried doing

```
   string.matches("rg .*);
```

but that gives accepts more than one word.

Comment: Have you looked up ANY documentation about regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

The dot matches any character so it also matches whitespaces. You can make an exception to this like so:

```
string.matches("rg [^ ]*");
```

Comment: Actually, a dot does not match *any* whitespace by default. But the pattern should work if a regular space is meant. Also, `"rg \\S+"` or even `"rg \\w+"` might turn out better alternatives for OP.

Comment: i am having a hard time figuring out the regex's... I need something like "rg \\w+" but the word that follows need to contain a ".". but w+ doesnt allow non word charaters, any help is appreciated

Comment: Use `"rg [\\w.]+"`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the pattern:

```
rg [\w.]+
```

`\w` matches any 'word' character

`.` matches the literal period

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string.matches( "rg [a-zA-Z0-9]*" );
```